# javascript to change the width of the table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my table and i want to change the width of all the  by javascript/jquery.

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" >  
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped dataTable no-footer" >   
            <thead class="bg-gray-active1">  
                <tr role="row">  
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" >Serial</th>  
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" >dsad</th>  
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" >vg</th>  
                    <th class="sorting_disabled" >sdfg</th>  
                </tr>  
            </thead>  
        </table>  
    </div>
```

I want the width of first `<th>` : 53px
I want the width of second `<th>` : 152px
I want the width of third `<th>` : 500px
I want the width of fourth `<th>` : 100px

Comment: If you are using datatable then there are syntax which can be used to change width of column. [Check Here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)

Comment: `$("th").first().width(53);` you can use id's instead of the th.first

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
$( "tr th:nth-child(1)" ).attr("width","53"); 
$( "tr th:nth-child(2)" ).attr("width","152"); 
$( "tr th:nth-child(3)" ).attr("width","500"); 
$( "tr th:nth-child(4)" ).attr("width","100");
```

It select every tr that have th as child(n). n is the number of their child

.attr is for adding html attribute. More info see here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp